# is it possible to change a class variable through its name in a njit function?

Tags: python, class, numba

I'm trying to modify a variable of a class through its name so basically what I do is calling `setattr` function. 
My issue is when I'm trying to do that with `numba` `njit` decorator, It doesn't work anymore.

So Is there a work around to do the same thing within `numba`?

```
import numba as nb

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a =0.

@nb.njit()
def test(A,s):
    setattr(A,s,1)

A = A()
s = 'a'
print(A.a)
test(A,s)
print(A.a)
```

### update

is it possible to call a function within the `test` function which is excluded of the `@nb.njit` decorator. In th ebelow example, the `var_update(A,s,1)` function could not be compiled?

```
import numba as nb

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a =0.

    def set_a(self,a):
        self.a=a

@nb.njit()
def test(A,s):
    var_update(A,s,1) # this function could not be compiled?

def var_update(Obj, s , val):
    setattr(Obj,s,val)

CA = A()
s = 'a'
print(CA.a)
test(CA,s)
print(CA.a)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do `A = A()`? Looks dirty.

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? I get a typing error from `numba` itself.

Comment: It crashes with a big message saying: This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: cannot determine Numba type of <class '__main__.A'> 
at the `setattr(A,s,1)` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to change a class variable through its name in a njit function?

No. Currently (with numba 0.43.1) that's not possible with nopython-mode numba functions. There are two reasons why it doesn't work in your example:

- In nopython mode numba only supports a very limited amount of classes. Custom classes (except `numba.jitclass`) are not supported.
- `setattr` is not supported by numba at all (see ["Built-in functions" section in "Supported Python features" in the numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.43.0/reference/pysupported.html#built-in-functions)).

However just in case you're interested in how you could set attributes of custom classes (but not with dynamic name) you can use `jitclass`:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.jitclass([('a', nb.float64)])
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0.0

@nb.njit
def test(instance):
    instance.a = 1

A = A()
print(A.a)
test(A)
print(A.a)
```

---

Note that if you want to use custom classes and `setattr` then my advise would be to do that **outside** of the numba functions. Numba is great with number-crunching and array-processing but it's not a general-purpose tool! If you want a more general-purpose tool then Cython may be better.

In my experience: If it's not about loops and not involving numbers or arrays then don't expect numba to be more efficient - which of course is over-simplified but served me as good guideline in the past (see for example my answer on ["When numba is effective?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55442354/5393381)).

Comment: my issue is I want change some variables of my class but I don't know which ones a priori. but as you said, it seems not possible.

Comment: Is it possible to call a function (`update_var`) that will perform the`setattr` in the `@nb.njit` `test` function but that function (`update_var`) will not be compile bu numba? I added info in the question.

Comment: @ymmx Since that's a seperate question I would propose to ask a new question. Changing the scope of the question invalidates existing answers. However short answer: No that's not possible everything inside a nopython function has to be nopython too (including function calls).

Comment: @ymmx Again: If you want to operate on custom classes then don't use numba for that, it's not something numba is (typically) good at.

Comment: I understand. I'm not very familiar with Cython, so I would rather stick with numba, but I will give it a try. Thanks for your answer